# How to make the native look for web app on mobile browser?

Tags: angular, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

As I know, we can do some responsiveness with the web app to make it look nicer on mobile devices.

However, looking into notion.so app. The UI of the app on tablet and mobile browser is completely different from the desktop version, it's not just responsive.

For example, when we resize the app on desktop, it just narrows down the width and height without changing any UI to look like on mobile.

My question is how can I do like that with my angular app?

Comment: CSS is how you apply style or design ascetics to HTML.
Yes, even with Angular and other slow Fast Food frameworks you can still apply any style you want.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is responsive design, I recommend looking into [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) for that. By settings `responsive breakpoints` you can decide on the structure of your app depending on the window's width / height

If you want an angular solution you can look into [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API): it is the angular way of doing it and also has a `responsive breakpoints` solution

It is difficult to implement though but start small and work your way from there, good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Angular is just a javascript framework used to build web apps.

Only **installed apps** on mobiles are supposed to have native look (they should look like ios app on ios and like android on android devices).

This can be achieved using hybrid frameworks like ionic. I suggest you check it out.

Comment: I take exception to your statement 'only installed apps'. You can make your site/pages look anyway you like. Just make them usable and look clean is the best advice I have.
having a PWA 'installed' is a nice to have and hopefully you earn the user's trust to engage with you at that level. Don't make it a must have for your PWA success.

Comment: Yeah a PWA can be installed but will it get the look and feel of a native application?? My idea of installed app is something installed from app store for example.

Comment: are you asking if the browser address bar is visible?
If you configure the manifest file to show the address bar it will. You control how it appears in this regard with different manifest properties.

I typically go with these:
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",